# VB.Net: Formatting Shapes

Tags: excel, vb.net, colors, shapes, msdn

Goals: Fill in shape and change/remove its border.

Issues: The color it's being filled with is becoming the opposite asked for (ask for red, its filled with blue).

```
myColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

Dim theShape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape = xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, (xlWorkSheet.Cells(theRow, theColumn)).Left, (xlWorkSheet.Cells(theRow, theColumn)).Top, 25, 14)

theShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = myColor.ToArgb()
```

Also, for changing the border, I found this... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shape.bordercolor.aspx.

I went through the process of installing the PowerPacks and adding `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Powerpacks` but it's still not giving me the ability to change the border color of my shape. Is there something else I need to do here?

```
theShape.borderColor = myColor.ToArgb
```

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: `myColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red` ?

Comment: @Hackerman that returns a blue rectangle. No idea why lol

Comment: @Hackerman yellow returns a light blue

Comment: can you build from the RGB properties into an excel.color https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.r(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that [**`Color.ToArgb()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an ARGB-integer in the format `AARRGGBB` but Excel expects a BGR-integer, which is in the format `BBGGRR`.

You are getting a blue shape because when you call `Color.Red.ToArgb()` it will pack an ARGB-integer like this:

```
255 (Alpha) | 255 (Red) | 0 (Green) | 0 (Blue)
```

But Excel interprets it like:

```
255 (Blue) | 0 (Green) | 0 (Red)
```

To fix it you will have to convert the color to a BGR-integer instead of an ARGB-integer.

This function should do the trick:

```
Public Function ToBgr(ByVal c As Color) As Long
    Return (CUInt(c.R) << 0 Or CUInt(c.G) << 8 Or CUInt(c.B) << 16) And &HFFFFFFFF
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
theShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ToBgr(myColor)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it appears the function doesn't work. It worked with red, but when I passed it blue and yellow it turned blue to red and yellow to light blue

Comment: I really appreciate your effort though, I would have never had any idea that's what was going on

Comment: @Bob : What if you remove `And &HFFFFFFFF`?

Comment: Red is still turning blue, and yellow still turning light blue.. I feel like there's an easy fix to something like this. I can't be the first person to run into this issue. My knowledge of VB.Net is just extremely lacking lol

Comment: @Bob : This then: `Return (CUInt(c.R) << 0 Or CUInt(c.G) << 8 Or CUInt(c.B) << 16 Or CUInt(c.A) << 24) And &HFFFFFFFF`? :I

Comment: I'll try this on my computer in 30 minutes or so.

Comment: Threw me a System.OverflowException. Thanks again for all your effort on this

Comment: @Bob : No problem, though you should wait to thank me until you've got a solution that works :). Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: Excel 2016 is the version

Comment: @Bob : Sorry for the delay, I had a little trouble getting the addin to work properly... I don't see the problem you're experiencing. All colors I'm trying are correct.

Comment: Finally figured it out, thanks again for all your hard work!

Comment: @Bob : No problem, but now I'm curious to what the problem was. :)

Comment: Honestly... I had three functions with very familiar names (one printed and filled a triangle, other two filled rectangle).. and I forgot my coffee this morning... and I changed the triangle and one rectangle function instead of both rectangle functions. My apologies on taking more of your time than it should have :(

Comment: @Bob : It's okay, it wasn't a problem. We all miss stuff sometimes. Besides, by contributing to Stack Overflow I am sort of volunteering to have people take some of my time. :)